# ASP security code if else doesn't work

Tags: security, if-statement, asp-classic

We have an old project we decide to implement a security code to our resume form I put that code bottom and my question is why if else statement doesn't work even code and form input was equal.

```
if (Session("random_code")<>request.form("input_code")) then 
  Response.Write "wrong code" 
else 
  Response.Write "true" 
end if
```

result is always wrong code I mean only first statement works.

Comment: start with a response.write of your session("randon_code") and request.form("input_code") and see what you actually have in there

Comment: I did it once they have value but it looks if else doesn't care about it

Comment: if your code block is properly formatted and the response.write output is really the same the if - else should work fine.

Comment: I know I try to put static values like 1=1 it works but when I put that variables it doesn't work, strange by the way thanks for the reply.

Comment: wild guess. try by adding a Cstr() around both session() and request.form()

Comment: wow, it works! thank you so much how could I choose your answer as a correct answer?

Comment: Glad it helped you. I'll add my previous comment as an answer, then you can choose this answer as the correct one if you wish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild guess. 
Try by adding a Cstr() around both session() and request.form()

This makes sure you are comparing string subtypes.